# Altium: Hierarchical Design not connecting properly?

Tags: altium, design

So I've been meaning to design a board that has many repeated components; basically making the user of the board able to create a state machine with discretely implemented ands for next state logic, ors to combine them, and then well, the D-Flipflops.

The structure of that looks like this:

[image: structure]

The problem I'm having however, is that Altium shows an "only one pin connected" error when I try to update my PCB from here, for all of the pins that were connected in this manner.

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

The Documentation on Repeat() is fairly lackluster, so I couldn't really find a solution by myself.

For clarification: all the and outs (a single one per instance) should go into all the or ins; the D outputs should all go into the flipflop_output block. The documentation page does it similarly, however there, the net names are uniform across the signal paths. Might that be the source of my problems?

My problem's solved as soon as those connections get recognized by Altium.

Comment: I tried renaming a single branch to all the same net name all over; no dice, same error.

Comment: Also tried 'pulling them apart', as in, I turned the OR-Blocks into 4 distinctive Or-Blocks, labelling the outputs D1 - D4, and connecting them to the bus. Same result; so something is off with the ports?

Answer (score 2):

Problem resolved: The buses in the hierarchical sheets themselves need Netlabels. I thought that was implied by the Ports, but that isn't so. Adding matching netlabels (such as input_in[1..6]) to the buses did the trick.